# error al ejecutar bat desde un programa en c#

Tags: java, c#, batch

Buenas tengo el siguiente bat, que ejecuto directamente y funciona sin problemas:

```
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /v CurrentVersion') DO set CurVer=%%B
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\%CurVer%" /v JavaHome') DO set JAVA_HOME=%%B
echo JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%
SET JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe
echo JAVA: %JAVA%
```

El problema surge cuando lo ejecuto desde un programa en c#, la funcion es la siguiente:

```
        Process proc = null;
        proc = new Process();

        proc.StartInfo.FileName = bat;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Xmx, Xmn, NAME);
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(proc.StartInfo.FileName);
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.Start();

        string procOutput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string procError = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        TextWriter outputlog = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "instancias\\pruebas\\.minecraft\\log.txt"));
        outputlog.Write(procOutput);
        outputlog.Close();

        TextWriter outputerror = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "instancias\\pruebas\\.minecraft\\error.txt"));
        outputerror.Write(procError);
        outputerror.Close();
```

El log que proporciona al ejecutar desde el programa en c#:

```
SET BASE=.\ 
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /v CurrentVersion') DO set CurVer=%B 
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\" /v JavaHome') DO set JAVA_HOME=%B 
echo JAVA_HOME:  
JAVA_HOME: 
SET JAVA=\bin\javaw.exe 
JAVA: \bin\javaw.exe
```

No se a que se debe que dejen de funcionar los `FOR` cuando este se ejecuta desde un programa en c#
Muchas gracias y un saludo

Comment: El problema es que no se guarda la variable del directorio donde esta java instalado

Comment: entonces el problema no es de c# o de java, es de su archivo.bat. Si encuentra la solución, recuerde [responder a su propia pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Saludos.

Comment: El bat lo ejecuto directamente y funciona sin problemas

Answer (score 0):

a ver si esto te funciona:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
Process process;

processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + bat);
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: no me sirve ya que necesito ejecutarlo con argumentos.

Comment: @Kaiserdj intentaste meter esos argumentos como cadena concatenada al final de la variable bat? Toma en cuenta que es como si lo ejecutaras desde la línea de comando, en vez de "cmd.exe", "/c " + bat)" pones "cmd.exe", "/c " + bat + " " + parametros)

Comment: No se ejecuta el bat